# Buttons (anchor Tags) inside Highslide doesn't works every time

Tags: highslide

I am using a highslide, which has buttons(Anchor Tags). When I open the popup, for the first time, Buttons work fine (Onclcik event triggers). But after every click, or if i open the popup again, Buttons dnt work.

PS- If I remove PreserveContent, it works fine but highslide doesnt opens at center always and if I keep it to true, this problem happens.

I want that my popup always opens in center with buttons working always..

Please help

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: We need more details to solve your issue: Is this an image popup (`hs.expand`) or a HTML popup (`hs.htmlExpand`), and if it’s a HTML popup - what type of HTML popup? Are you using `hs.align = 'center';` to center the popup in the page? What Highslide JavaScript file are you using? Can you give more details about the buttons in the popup? Actually - the best would be a link to your live page.